# How to make the toString method automatically output a JSON string without manually concatenating the JSON string?

Tags: java, json

The output produced by the toString method in Java does not meet my needs. I am looking for a way to enable the toString method to output a json string. Moreover, because this function will be used very frequently, it is best to be uniformly configured. You can use a unified configuration point to let toString output json. In the worst case, he should also implement it by adding annotation to each class.
I previously placed my hope on the lombok library, however, the lombok community clearly refused to implement this functionality. Jackson doesn't seem to have this feature either. Are there any other ways to achieve this requirement?

```
public class User {
    private String userId;

    private String uswrName;

    // I don't want to write any toString method
    //public String toString () {}
}

User user = new User();
user.setUserName("xxxxxxx");

// I want him to output a JSON string
System.out.print(user);
```

Comment: is it sufficient to wrap in `"` or is more needed? (a single string enclosed in quotes _is_ valid JSON) I'd expect a method producing json to be like `toJSON()` or embedded into a class that collects a variety of outputs

Comment: I don't think it can be achieved without overriding the `toString` method. Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: When debugging or reproducing problems with my program, I need to copy objects from other environments to my debugging environment.
Deserializing using json is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a `toString()` method in your **User** class, then don't have one. Do as @Ti7 suggests, add a `toJSON()` method to your **User** class, for example, use the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) API (com.fasterxml.jackson) in your **User** class:

```
public class User {

    private String userId;
    private String userName;

    public User() { }

    public User(String userId, String userName) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * Converts this instance of User to a JSON string in either Compact-Print 
     * or in default Pretty-Print.<br>
     * 
     * @param asCompactPrint (boolean - varArg - Optional) By default Compact-
     * Print is false which tells the method to create the JSON string in a 
     * Pretty-Print format. If boolean <b>true</b> is supplied then a Compact-
     * Print format JSON string is returned.
     * 
     * @return (String) The current Object instance converted to a JSON String.
     */
    public String toJSON (boolean... asCompactPrint) {
        boolean compact = false;
        if (asCompactPrint.length > 0) {
            compact = asCompactPrint[0];
        }

        String resultString = null;
        
        try {
            com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper
                = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
            if (compact) {
                // Java object to Compact-Print JSON string:
                resultString = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
            }
            else {
                // Java object to Pretty-Print JSON string:
                resultString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(this);
            }
        }
        catch (com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        
        return resultString;
    }
}
```

**Example Use:**

```
User user = new User("A0001", "Fred FlintStone");
System.out.println(user.toJSON());
```

**Console Output:**

```
{
  "userName" : "Fred FlintStone",
  "userID" : "A0001"
}
```

---

### Edit:

**As Per Comment: `However I don't want to write template code in a lot of classes.`:**

Fair enough, then create a ToJSON class and place the method in there (slightly modified of course), for example:

**The ToJSON Class:**

```
public class ToJSON {
    
    /**
     * Requires the following Jackson JAR files:<pre>
     *     jackson-databind-2.16.1.jar 
     *     jackson-annotations-2.16.1.jar
     *     jackson-core-2.16.1.jar
     * </pre>
     * 
     * Converts the supplied class Object instance or List interface of class 
     * Object (ie: {@code List<User>}) to a JSON string in either Compact-Print or in default 
     * Pretty-Print.<br>
     * 
     * If a List Interface of class object was supplied then a JSON array string is 
     * generated.<br><br>
     * 
     * @param classObject (Object) The class object instance to convert to JSON.<br>
     * 
     * @param asCompactPrint (boolean - varArg - Optional) By default Compact-Print 
     * is false which tells the method to create the JSON string in a Pretty-Print 
     * format. If boolean <b>true</b> is supplied then a Compact-Print format 
     * JSON string is returned.<br>
     * 
     * @return (String) The current Object converted to a JSON String or is a 
     * List of class Object was supplied (ie: {@code List<User>}) then a JSON 
     * array string is returned.
     */
    public static String objectToJSON (Object classObject, boolean... asCompactPrint) {
        boolean compact = false;
        if (asCompactPrint.length > 0) {
            compact = asCompactPrint[0];
        }

        String resultString = null;
        
        try {
            com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper
                = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
            if (compact) {
                // Java object to Compact-Print JSON string:
                //resultString = mapper.writeValueAsString(classObject);
                resultString = mapper.writeValueAsString(classObject);
            }
            else {
                // Java object to Pretty-Print JSON string:
                resultString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(classObject);
            }
        }
        catch (com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        
        return resultString;
    }
}
```

then to use it:

```
// As Pretty-Print:
System.out.println(ToJSON.objectInstanceToJSON(user));

// As Compact-Print:
System.out.println(ToJSON.objectInstanceToJSON(user, true));
```

You can also generate a *JSON Array* string if you happen to have a List Interface of User (ie: `List<User>`), for example:

```
/* Note: The User class used for this particular example
   contains instance variables `id` and `name`:    */
java.util.List<User> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
list.add(new User("A002", "Fred Flintstone"));
list.add(new User("A004", "Tracey Johnson"));
list.add(new User("A006", "Doug Gill"));
list.add(new User("A008", "Tom Jones"));
String jsonString = ToJSON.objectToJSON(list);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

This would print to the following to the Console Window:

```
[ {
  "id" : "A002",
  "name" : "Fred Flintstone"
}, {
  "id" : "A004",
  "name" : "Tracey Johnson"
}, {
  "id" : "A006",
  "name" : "Doug Gill"
}, {
  "id" : "A008",
  "name" : "Tom Jones"
} ]
```

Comment: However I don't want to write template code in a lot of classes.

Comment: @王先生 - See the **Edit** section within the answer above regarding your comment.